# In an NFA that recognizes L(ab) where ab is a regular expression, what is the point of the empty string transition?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm reading Introduction to Computational Theory by Michael Sipser. He provides the NFA below as one that recognizes the language of the regular expression $ab$.

What is the purpose of the middle two states and the $\varepsilon$ transition between them? Could this NFA be designed without them and still work as intended?

[image: re]

Here's another example of an NFA that recognizes the language described by $aba$. Again, I'm confused by the addition of the empty string transitions and the extra states.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is part of the construction to obtain a finite automaton for each regular expression. This construction is known as Thompson's construction and works recursively. Given automata $A(e_1)$ and $A(e_2)$ for expressions $e_1$ and $e_2$, instructions are given to build new automata for the expressions $e_1 + e_2$, $e_1\cdot e_2$ and $e_1^*$. These new automata contain a lot of $\varepsilon$-edges to connect the original parts.

Hence the purpose of the example is not to give an efficient automaton (that is a no-brainer for $ab$) but to illustrate these constructions.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying that those $\epsilon$-transition are useless. For the regular expression $ab$, a DFA with just three states (the initial state, an intermediate state, and a final state) and two transitions would suffice.

A similar reasoning applies to the second NFA, where $4$ states are enough.

I don't have the book to check, but maybe those are just examples of some of the many possible NFAs that accept the regular languages you mentioned?